# ASP.NET Core Web API with Identity - React SPA Frontend - Identity cookies not saved to browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, cors, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API, I use Identity to manage users. As FE I have SPA application in React (I need to have both of them on different server).

The problem is that login etc from FE doesn't work. I can login with the first request, but the browser doesn't save the authentication cookies from BE (see picture), even though I can see the Set-Cookie in the request. It doesn't work when testing on localhost or when deployed on the server.

[image]

[image]

I tried:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; 
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
}

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowHost", builder => {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
               .AllowCredentials()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

app.UseCors("AllowHost");
```

Comment: if they are on different servers, when the backend sets a cookie, it is set to a different domain, so you can't see it from frontend.  If you navigate the browser to your back-end's domain, you will see the cookie(s).

Comment: I send a request from FE, BE replies and in the header I have a set-cookie request. I can see that in FE.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: It's working as designed.  Only the backend domain can see cookies set from that domain.  Those cookies will be sent along with requests to the backend domain.  Additionally, if set same-site lax or strict (default is lax) they will only be sent from the same-origin.  It looks like you have those set as same-site none, so they can be sent from a cross-origin context.  You can confirm that by setting the browser to the back-end's domain and then checking the dev console.  It should show you all the cookie's settings.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that's not the way to set it up for my requirements... So I have to use something else to log in (JWT maybe)

Comment: Or is there some way to use ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Maybe check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-token-based-authentication

Comment: ¨Thanks, i will take a look.

Comment: @pcalkins You wrote: [...] _if set same-site lax or strict (default is lax) they will only be sent from the same-origin._ Not only from the same origin, but from any same-site origin. [Don't conflate origin with site](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/).

Comment: I think the only difference between same-site and same-origin would be the port.  Origin takes the port into account, while same-site does not.  I guess this is why dev tools isn't showing the cookies with the different port... though it would pass the "same-site" test for the cookie to be sent... but not the same-origin test.